# Weyl's formula and Cartan decompositiom of semisimple lie algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

I'm working on  the article of  Benkart and Osborn " Flexible Lie-admissible algebras", specially,  i'm working on the lemma 3.1,  this lemma represent the dimension of L-module homomorphisms of $L\otimes L$ into L which equals the number  of times L appears in the decomposition of $L\otimes L$ into irreducible L-modules. In the course of the proof of this lemma,  i ' m trying to show the method but  i don't understand how they got the adjoint decomposition  represented in the table I and where appear the adjoint representation  in this decompoaition. Also, how can i use the weyl's formula in this calculation.